# Multiple files upload from one form php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload two files from single form. However it's not getting uploaded to the folder location, I'm not able to find the error, too.

Here is my code:

**HTML File**

```
<form action='/uploadfile.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='photograph'>
    <input type='file' name='addressproof'>
    <input type='submit' class="button alt" value='SAVE'>
</form>
```

**uploadfile.php**

```
    if($_FILES['photograph']['error']==0){
        $info = pathinfo($_FILES['photograph']['name']);
        $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
        $newname = "photograph_".$userid.".".$ext; 

        if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='png' || $ext=='jpeg' || $ext=='pdf'){
            $target = '/user_documents/photograph/'.$newname;
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photograph']['tmp_name'], $target);
        }
    }

    if($_FILES['addressproof']['error']==0){
        $info = pathinfo($_FILES['addressproof']['name']);
        $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
        $newname = "address_proof_".$userid.".".$ext; 

        if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='png' || $ext=='jpeg' || $ext=='pdf'){
            $target = '/user_documents/address_proof/'.$newname;
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['addressproof']['tmp_name'], $target);
        }
    }
```

Can somebody help identify the error?

Comment: do your folder have 777 permission?

Comment: Yes they have 777 permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_FILES['addressproof']['error']==0){
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['addressproof']['name']);
    $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
    $newname = "address_proof_".$userid.".".$ext; 

    if($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='png' || $ext=='jpeg' || $ext=='pdf'){
        $target = 'user_documents/address_proof/'.$newname;  // remove the slash before user_documents/address_proof/
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['addressproof']['tmp_name'], $target);
    }
}
```